# problem with refactoring nodejs for maintenance

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring

So the following code is functional, just one function with variation of specs, but I am kind of suspicious, I believe it looks ugly specially with the callback, it really needs refactoring, any ideas on how it can be refactored to be maintainable and overcome flaws?

```js
await rps_id.map((rp_id) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    Part.Model.updateOne({
                            _id: rp_id
                        }, {
                            invoiceId: invoice._id
                        }).then(function(result) {
                            return resolve();
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            reject();
                        });
                });
            });
```

this is the rest of the code: https://codepen.io/0xf10yd/pen/PopRWpz

I'd appreciate your help a lot, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already make use of `await`, so I'd suggest changing all the code to use async/await to retain consistency.

The returned Promise inside the arrow function actually doesn't serve a purpose. You resolve inside a `.then` and reject inside a `.catch`. So unless there was some extra handling of the response or the thrown error, the returned promise is redundant.

Since `Part.Model.updateOne` already returns a promise (since you're using `.then` on it), I'm guessing you could probably trim it a lot like so:

```js
await rps_id.map((rp_id) => Part.Model.updateOne({
            _id: rp_id
        }, {
            invoiced: invoice._id
        });
```

I'm not really able to test this, but it should work just like your code.